# How to increment my row counter variable in my while loop?

Tags: java, while-loop, apache-poi, increment

I am trying to read in each row that has data in the first cell into an ArrayList of Objects. My problem is that my code doesn't seem to be incrementing my counter past the first row. Am I missing something simple?

## Code

```
        try
            {
                wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(fileName));
            } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        catch (IOException e)
            {   
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(2);
        ArrayList<Object> obj = new ArrayList<Object>();
        int rowIndex = 0;
        int cellIndex = 0;
        XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
        Iterator<Cell> rowItr = row.iterator();

        while(rowIndex <= sheet.getLastRowNum())
            {
                if(row.getCell(0) == null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                else
                    {
                        while(rowItr.hasNext() && rowItr.next() != null)
                                    {
                                        XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(cellIndex);

                                        if(cell == null)
                                            {
                                                continue;
                                            }
                                        else
                                            {       
                                                obj.add(row.getCell(cellIndex).toString());
                                            }
                                        cellIndex++;
                                    }

                                rowIndex++;
                                cellIndex = 0;

                            }

                        System.out.println(obj.toString());
                    }
                rowIndex++;
            }   
    }
```

## Output

```
[ValuSmart Series 1120 Double Hung]
```

... *I get this output 72 times since there are 72 rows in the sheet*

## Isolated Loop

```
ArrayList<Object> obj = new ArrayList<Object>();
int rowCounter = 16;
        int x = 0;

        while(rowCounter <= 21)
            {

                XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(rowCounter);
                Iterator<Cell> rowItr = row.iterator();

                while(rowItr.hasNext() && rowItr.next() != null)
                    {

                                XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(x);


                                if(cell == null)
                                    {
                                        continue;
                                    }
                                else
                                    {

                                        obj.add(row.getCell(x).toString());
                                    }
                        x++;

                    }

                rowCounter++;
                x = 0;
            }
        System.out.println(obj.toString());
```

Comment: Using a debugger and executing the code line by line would help you find the problem, and would save you countless hours of debugging time in the future. Why not start doing it now?

Comment: What's the purpose of your iterator?

Comment: int rowIndex = 0;                                                                             XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(rowIndex); Tehcnically your 'row' object is already initialized outside of the loop and you are just playing with the same object inside the loop.

Comment: My iterator goes through each cell in the row and adds the cell to the ArrayList object if it is not null. @shmosel

Comment: @YohannesGebremariam Are you telling me to put those two lines of code inside the loop?

Comment: @KyleHarbour Your iterator doesn't do a thing, other than count elements perhaps. You're not using the value returned by `next()`.

Comment: @shmosel correction, my iterator makes sure the next cell in the row is not null. If it isn't, that cell is added to the arraylist

Comment: You're not actually skipping any indexes, so all it does is possibly reduce the total amount of cells, while still including nulls.

Comment: @shmosel I'm not following?

Comment: if I isolate the loop, it does exactly what I want for a block of rows. I'm trying to figure out how to read the entire sheet using a counter that increments the row I should be reading @shmosel

Comment: If it does what you want, it's only by coincidence. There's no correlation between your iterator results and the cell lookup. The iterator skips nulls, but the cell lookup uses an index which is incremented sequentially. Say you have 3 cells, of which the second is null. The first iteration and lookup will work fine. The second round will be skipped because `next()` returns null. On the third round, the index is still 1, which points to a null cell, so the third cell will be skipped as well. The standard pattern is to use *either* an iterator *or* an index. Mixing the two is not a good idea.

Comment: @shmosel so remove the iterator, as it is basically useless? and just increment the index variable I initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not select the next row anywhere, and your loops are confusing and switch between index- and iterator-based lookups. Try a simple *enhanced for* loop:

```
for (Row row : sheet) {
    for (Cell cell : row) {
        if (cell != null) {
            obj.add(row.getCell(x).toString());
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(obj.toString());
```

Comment: Last thing. once a cell is null, I don't want to read that row anymore. I'm struggling to figure out logic for that @shmosel

Comment: @KyleHarbour Change the `if` to `if (cell == null) { break; }` and move the next line out.

Comment: Using the enhanced loop, you will only get cells that exist, so you will not get a null cell. What is the purpose of breaking on null cells? Do the rows in your spreadsheet have missing cells in the middle of the row?